# Sending mail to an external server?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I'm currently experimenting with working with Outlook.com for an email server, and have MX records set up to point there and the like. How can I configure systems like postfix to use external servers for mail? When I try to use functions like PHP's `mail()` for example, the server logs return this line, obviously because `user` isn't a user on my system, but rather is on an external mail server.

```
ABBAB100B92: to=<user@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.04/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "user")
```

Might it be easier to run a mail server right off of the VPS I'm hosting my website on, so that everything stays local? Or is that not a very good idea?

System is an Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Postfix, you need to set `relayhost` in your configuration, and some other options as well. There are many articles online explaining how to do this, for example [this one.](http://www.howtoforge.com/postfix_relaying_through_another_mailserver)

> Might it be easier to run a mail server right off of the VPS I'm hosting my website on, so that everything stays local?

I don't think that would be easier.

> Or is that not a very good idea?

No, it's not, because email coming directly from your server will probably have a higher probability of being classified as spam based on its IP address than email coming from a reputable provider such as Outlook.com.

Comment: Right. I was able to set up the relay properly, however, in this particular case when I'm using a contact form, when the email is relayed through outlook, the from address is stripped because of the SMTP server.

What I end up receiving is something like:

`To: user1@example.com From: user1@example.com`

Is there any way to preserve this info? I was able to to it when email was hosted on my server before moving to a VPS.

Comment: @NoelForte ah, yes, both Outlook.com and GMail rewrite FROM addresses for anti-spam reasons. You could add an additional header I suppose.

Comment: What if I just set up an email server directly on my server? I know you said this isn't easier, and has potential to be blacklisted, but don't PTR Reverse DNS Records and SPF Records, as well as SSL Certs help prevent blacklisting?

Comment: Yes, good points. OK, maybe that would be better for this use case.

Comment: One more question: Would you recommend using a separate VPS for email? Or is it better to run email and apache off of one box?

Comment: I don't have any advice to give on that one, sorry.